# URL.createObjectURL and charset UTF-8

Tags: javascript

i have problem with encoding my text

```js
var description = "jak używać?"
        var blob = new Blob([description], {
            type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8;"
        });
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        console.log(url)
```

where i enter to url my description isnt same and return jak uĹźywaÄ? What i doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Add `Byte order mark` to the array header.

```
blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", description]);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18925211/9867895

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

...

```
var blob = new Blob([**"\ufeff",** description], {
```

...

Answer (score 0):

`URL.creatObjectUrl` doesn't seem to work with raw UTF-8 strings. The solution provided for binary data https://stackoverflow.com/a/36955941/70716 should work. the answers to [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16245767/70716) also include some additional explanation of the issue and alternative code examples.